# VHDL Flip Flop Syntax Error

Tags: vhdl, flipflop, synthesis

I'm trying to figure out how to VHDL, and am having some difficulties writing a simple flip flop. I want a T flip flop that runs strictly off of the clock, changing state every time it receives a rising edge.

The syntax errors are somewhat cryptic and I'm having difficulty figuring out what is wrong.

```
library lattice;
use lattice.components.all;
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;

entity blinker is
    port(
            clk     :   IN  STD_LOGIC;
            ledout  :   OUT STD_LOGIC
    );
end blinker;

architecture Behavioral of blinker is
    signal ledState: STD_LOGIC;
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
        --if clk'event and clk='1' then
            if ledState = '1' then
                ledout <= '0';
            elsif ledState = '0' then
                ledout <= '1';
            endif;
        endif;
    end process;

    ledout <= led_state;

end Behavioral;
```

I attempted two methods of running on a rising edge, neither seemed to make a difference. This is what the output looks like:

[image]

I'm completely lost at this point. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a few issues:

**1.** `endif;` should be `end if;`

**2.** You already have assignments to `ledout` within your process, but then you attempt to assign a value to it again in the last line `ledout <= led_state;`. You can't have multiple drivers for a given signal.

**3.** Your code is a little over-complicated. You can simplify the toggle of signal `ledState` like so: `ledState <= not ledState;` without the embedded if/elsif clause.

**4.** One of the error messages is pointing out a typo you made in the last line `ledout <= led_state;`, where I think you meant `ledout <= ledState`;

Try this instead:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity blinker is
    port(
            clk     :   IN  std_logic;
            ledout  :   OUT std_logic
    );
end blinker;

architecture Behavioral of blinker is
    signal ledState: std_logic := '0';
begin
    process(clk)
    begin
        if(rising_edge(clk)) then
            ledState <= not ledState;
        end if;
    end process;

    ledout <= ledState;

end Behavioral;
```

RTL
[image: RTL]

Comment: Well I guess I'm not following that tutorial anymore. Thanks for pointing those out, it works now. Out of curiosity what did you use to generate the RTL diagram? I'm using Lattice Diamond as my IDE.

Comment: @alphasierra Glad I could help. I typically use Xilinx FPGAs. I used Vivado for the RTL diagram.